# How can I use monaco yaml plugin with Monaco Webpack Loader Plugin?

Tags: webpack, es6-modules, monaco-editor, webpack-5

I have ESM version of Monaco set up using the Webpack Loader plugin. I want to add monaco yaml plugin, and I struggle to understand how do I do that. I'm using the [Integrating the ESM version of the Monaco Editor](https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor/blob/main/docs/integrate-esm.md) guide and [Monaco Yam plugin README](https://github.com/remcohaszing/monaco-yaml/blob/main/README.md).

The documentation on yaml plugin says to set up `getWorker` function in `MonacoEnvironment; however, the ESM documentation says to either use Webpack loader, or to set up` getWorkerUrl` function, so three different ways to set this up in total.

- The names of `getWorker` and `getWorkerUrl` functions hint that they are interchangeable — are they? Who calls these functions?
- `getWorkerUrl` uses `./ts.worker.bundle.js` for typescript, whereas `getWorker` uses `monaco-editor/esm/vs/language/typescript/ts.worker` url to create typescript worker. These urls seem very similar. Is there 1-to-1 relationship here, and what is it? If there is, where is the `monaco-editor/esm/vs/language/typescript` prefix added?
- Monaco Yaml `getWorker` function source uses `monaco-yaml/yaml.worker` url for the plugin. If urls in `getWorkerUrl` are automatically added `monaco-editor/...` prefixes, how can I use `getWorkerUrl` function with this url?
- Options for Monaco Webpack plugin aren't documented, so I'm trying to understand their meaning from types. There's `IFeatureDefinition` with `label`, `entry`, `worker` of type `IWorkerDefinition`, which in turn also has `id` and `string`. How do all of these properties relate to the `getWorkerUrl` parameters of `moduleId` and `label` (is that the label of a feature or a worker? What's the difference?) and the return value of url?
- What's the easiest and most reliable way to check if monaco yaml plugin has been successfully loaded by the editor?

Overall, there's no proper information about exact contracts of all this configuration, just simple examples, and a lot of things that seem to be vaguely similar between all the three methods (`getWorker`, `getWorkerUrl` and `MonacoWebpackPlugin`) without any clarifications, so I just feel very confused by it. These questions are my best attempt at structuring all the information available to me.

Comment: I have also asked my question here: https://github.com/remcohaszing/monaco-yaml/issues/173

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added the answer [to the plugin's README file](https://github.com/remcohaszing/monaco-yaml/blob/main/README.md#using-monaco-webpack-loader-plugin):

You can extend the plugin's configuration. Extend your
`webpack.config.js` file with the following:

```js
import { MonacoWebpackPlugin } from 'monaco-editor-webpack-plugin';

export default {
  // ...the rest of your webpack configuration...
  plugins: [
    new MonacoWebpackPlugin({
      languages: ['yaml'],
      customLanguages: [
        {
          label: 'yaml',
          entry: 'monaco-yaml',
          worker: {
            id: 'monaco-yaml/yamlWorker',
            entry: 'monaco-yaml/yaml.worker',
          },
        },
      ],
    }),
  ],
};
```

You can also refer to the
[example](https://github.com/remcohaszing/monaco-yaml/tree/main/examples/monaco-editor-webpack-plugin)
of a complete project.